# get the value of firebase key and value without knowing the parent

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have the following database set up:

```
-Users
-Groups
   -Groupname
      -Cost
      -Creator
      -Members
         -uid1: points
         -uid2: points
```

I am trying to query to get the Groupname and cost only if the the current users uid is in the Members area for that specific Groupname.  The issue is I won't know the group name, as they will all be chosen by the user, so it is not static.  Is there any sort of getParent function with firebase database?

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a `FIRDataSnapshot` object for the *Members* node you can use the `ref` (and `FIRDatabaseReference.parent`) properties to walk up the hierarchy. For instance:

```
let members: FIRDataSnapshot = ...
let groupName: FIRDatabaseReference = members.ref.parent!
// Inspect the groupName ref...
```

But, as I said before, you need a `FIRDataSnapshot` handy to make this work :-)

Comment: I have been using FIRDataSnapshot, but the issue I ran into is that I am unable to get to the Member as I do not know the parent (Groupname).  Is there a way to search for any instance of (user.uid) throughout the entire database to get around that?  I was unable to find a way to do so without knowing the entire path to get to the (user.uid)

Comment: @dgelinas21 I don't think that's possible at all, sorry. You may need to *denormalize* your data such that you can write your query effectively. This [Firebase guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure) might help you doing so. Best of luck ;-)

Comment: you have to query all the `Groups` the loop using the children to get in the `Members` node, sorry i don't know how to develop swift but this is the only way

Comment: @PauloMattos okay, I will have to modify my code to add the information to the user upon join then.  Just wanted to make sure there was no alternative before doing so.

Comment: @dgelinas21If you are feeling adventurous, you may also consider doing this using the newly released [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases) feature. Might payoff if you are targeting multiple *client* platforms (and can tolerate some database update latency).

Answer (score 0):

You gotta play with the security rules :-

***Security Rules***

```
{
"rules": {
    "Groups" : {

     "$Group_name" :{

        // Will only allow the user's who are members to this group access
        // this group node to read; you can modify your write rules similarly...

       ".read" : "root.child('Groups').child($Group_name).child('MemberID').child(auth.uid).exists()",
      ".write" : "auth != null"

       }
    },

  "Users" : {

    "$uid" : {

         ".read" : "auth.uid == $uid",
         ".write" : "auth.uid == $uid"

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Security rules act as an internal filter's; So you don't need to worry parent node the user won't be allowed inside that particular *$Group_name* node until unless its a member to that group.

Comment: Accept and up vote this as answer if it solves your issue, Happy Coding :)